# Transferring variables between functions Python

Tags: python, function, variables

```
def name():
        name=input("what is your name?")
        print()
def print():
        print(name)
```

Hello new to programming!

I'm making a simple game and need to transfer names and scores through different functions much like the code displayed. Is there a way to make this work (Python)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a value from a function the clearest and most standard way to do it is to return the value:

```
def ask_name():
    name = input("what is your name?")
    return name # this gives the value back to the calling function

def another_function():
    name = ask_name() # this assigns the returned value to the variable "name"
    print(name)
```

Also, don't define functions with the same name as built-in functions like `print()`:

```
def print(name_to_print):
    print(name_to_print)
```

If you call this function it will not print anything.  Rather, when it calls `print(name_to_print)` it will call itself, not the built-in `print()`. Then that will call it self again over and over again until your program fails with the error "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".